# Consider three nonzero matrices $A, B, C$ such that $ABB^t=CBB^t$.Then which property $A$ and $C$ share

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Consider three nonzero matrices $A, B, C$ such that $ABB^t=CBB^t$. Then which of the following are true?

(A) $r(A) =r(C)$

(B) nonzero eigenvalues of $A$ and $C$ are identical

(C) $AB=CB$

(D) none of the above

**Try:**
Since $ABB^t=CBB^t\implies \det(ABB^t) =\det(CBB^t) $
$\implies \det(A) \det(B) \det(B^t) =\det(C) \det(B) \det(B^t)$
$\implies \det(A) (\det(B) ^2=\det(C)(\det(B))^2$ [since $\det(B) =\det(B^t)$].

The above implies that $\det(A) =\det(C)$ which is possible iff they have the same set of nonzero eigenvalues and all the eigenvalues are nonzero . But if they have a 0 eigenvalue then we can't claim that. How to conclude?

Comment: Are all of these matrices square?

Comment: That is not mentioned though. Then my calculation is totally wrong. Cause determinant is not defined then.

Comment: "The above implies that det $(A)=$ det $(C)$ which is possible iff they have the same set of nonzero eigenvalues and all the eigenvalues are nonzero " is not correct. Consider the matrices $\begin{bmatrix} 4&0\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\ 0&2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @R_D Yes. That was another mistake. I messed the whole thing. (+1) for your observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items (a) and (b) are certainly false. Take $A=B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:0&0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ \:0&2\end{pmatrix}$. Item (c) is true, and it relies on the fact that $B$ and $BB^t$ have the same column space. To see this, assume $B$ is $m\times n$, and fix $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\text{Col}(B)=\text{Col}(BB^t)$ we can find $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Bx=BB^ty$. So we have $$ABx=ABB^ty=CBB^ty=CBx$$ Since $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ was chosen arbitrarily we must have $AB=CB$.